# Workaround to docker run "--env-file" supplied file not being evaluated as expected

Tags: docker

My current setup for running a docker container is on the lines of this:

1. I've got a `main.env` file:

```
# Main
export PRIVATE_IP=\`echo localhost\`
export MONGODB_HOST="$PRIVATE_IP"
export MONGODB_URL="mongodb://$MONGODB_HOST:27017/development"
```

2. In my service file (upstart), I source this file `. /path/to/main.env`
3. I then call `docker run` with multiple `-e` for each of the environment variables I want inside of the container. In this case I would call something like: `docker run -e MONGODB_URL=$MONGODB_URL ubuntu bash`
4. I would then expect `MONGODB_URL` inside of the container to equal `mongodb://localhost:27017/development`. Notice that in reality `echo localhost` is replaced by a `curl` to amazon's api for an actual `PRIVATE_IP`.

This becomes a bit unwieldy when you start having more and more environment variables you need to give your container. There is a fine point to see here which is that the environment variables need to be resolved ***at run time***, such as with a call to `curl` or by referring to other env variables.

The solution I was hoping to use is:

1. calling `docker run` with an `--env-file` parameter such as this:

```
# Main
PRIVATE_IP=\`echo localhost\`
MONGODB_HOST="$PRIVATE_IP"
MONGODB_URL="mongodb://$MONGODB_HOST:27017/development"
```

2. Then my `docker run` command would be significantly shortened to `docker run --env-file=/path/to/main.env ubuntu bash` (keep in mind usually I've got around 12-15 environment variables.

This is where I hit my problem which is that inside the container none of the variables resolve as expected. Instead I end up with:

- PRIVATE_IP=`echo localhost`
- MONGODB_HOST="$PRIVATE_IP"
- MONGODB_URL="mongodb://$MONGODB_HOST:27017/development"

I could circumvent this by doing the following:

1. Sourcing the `main.env` file.
2. Creating a file containing just the names of the variables I want (meaning docker would search for them in the environment).
3. Then calling `docker run` with this file as an argument to `--env-file`. This would work but would mean I would need to maintain two files instead of one, and really wouldn't be that big of an improvement of the current situation.

What I would prefer is to have the variables resolve as expected.

The closest question to mine that I could find is:
[12factor config approach with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177402/12factor-config-approach-with-docker)

Comment: I noticed that your `main.env` is setting your vars as literal strings. Have you tried removing `"` & `'`? You can read more about how Docker handles literals here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) the env file syntax should be simple key=value items. Not sure how the 'export' would be handled in your case.

Answer (score 10):

So I just faced this issue as well, what solved it for me was I specified the --env-file or -e KEY=VAL **before** the name of the container image. For example

Broken:

```
docker run my-image --env-file .env
```

Fixed:

```
docker run --env-file .env my-image
```

Comment: Oh my God I wasted over an hour on this

Answer (score 5):

- Ceate a .env file

> ```
>  example: test=123 val=Guru
> ```

- Execute command

> docker run -it --env-file=.env  bash

- Inside the bash verify using

> echo $test (should print 123)

Answer (score 4):

Both `--env` and `--env-file` setup variables as is and do not replace nested variables.

[Solomon Hykes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/docker-user/FyCWLC38Ueg/gh_1-NMc2NYJ) talks about configuring containers at run time and the the various approaches. The one that should work for you is to volume mounting the main.env from host into the container and sourcing it.

Comment: "sourcing it" means you need bash or some other shell and that means having lots of cruft in the container when, in my case, I just want the executable

Answer (score 0):

creating an ENV file that is nothing more than key/value pairs can be processed in normal shell commands and appended to the environment. Look at the bash -a pragma.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a startup script that can be run when the container starts. So if your current docker file looks something like this

```
From ...
...
CMD command
```

Change it to

```
From ...
...
ADD start.sh start.sh
CMD ["start.sh"]
```

In your **start.sh** script do the following:

```
export PRIVATE_IP=\`echo localhost\`
export MONGODB_HOST="$PRIVATE_IP"
export MONGODB_URL="mongodb://$MONGODB_HOST:27017/development"
command
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to this. If I passed the contents of the env file to docker as separate -e directives then everything ran fine however if I passed the file using --env-file the container failed to run properly.

Turns out there were some spurious line endings in the file (I had copied from windows and ran docker in Ubuntu). When I removed them the container ran the same with --env or --env-file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using `docker run` in a separate run script `run.sh` file, since I wanted the credentials `ADMIN_USER` and `ADMIN_PASSWORD` to be accessible in the container, but not show up in the command.

Following the other answers and passing a separate environment file with `--env` or `--env-file` didn't work for my image (though it worked for the [Bash image](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash)). What worked was creating a separate env file...

```
# env.list
ADMIN_USER='username'
ADMIN_PASSWORD='password'
```

...and sourcing it in the run script when launching the container:

```
# run.sh
source env.list
docker run -d \
    -e ADMIN_USER=$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER \
    -e ADMIN_PASSWORD=$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD \
    image_repo/name:tag
```