# docker ENV vs RUN export

Tags: docker

Let's say I want combine these commands

```
RUN command_1
ENV FOO bar
RUN command_2
```

into

```
RUN command_1 && export FOO=bar && command_2
```

and was wondering if setting the variable with `RUN export` vs `ENV` was equivalent.

In other words, is there a difference between these commands in a Dockerfile?

```
ENV FOO bar
```

vs

```
RUN export FOO=bar
```

Answer (score 284, accepted):

As illustrated by [issue 684](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/684), `export` won't persist across images. (Don't forget that each Dockerfile directive will generate an intermediate container, committed into an intermediate image: that image won't preserve the exported value)
**[`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)** will:

> The environment variables set using `ENV` will persist when a container is run from the resulting image.
> You can view the values using `docker inspect`, and change them using `docker run --env <key>=<value>`.

The issue was illustrating that with:

```
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar # from directly in builder
```

> When I do `docker run [img] bash -c 'echo $PATH'` it never includes `/foo/bar`.

### Try it

Create a new dockerfile containing:

```
FROM centos:6
ENV FOO=foofoo
RUN export BAR=barbar
RUN export BAZ=bazbaz && echo "$FOO $BAR $BAZ"
```

Then build it. The output of the last step is:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN export BAZ=bazbaz && echo "$FOO $BAR $BAZ"
 ---> Running in eb66196b238d
foofoo  bazbaz
```

You can see:

- `FOO` persists through intermediate containers, thanks to the `ENV` keyword;
- `BAR` doesn't persist on the next step, because of the `export` command;
- `BAZ` is correctly displayed because the variable is used in the same Docker image layer on the same container, since:

  > Each instruction in a Dockerfile creates a layer in the image.

  [Source](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#images)

Comment: (I guess yes, but:) Does it mean that `docker` e.g. `run` with `--env-file` or `--env` will export those (by these option arguments) variables? Sorry for bumping up on such an old answer but a websearch just brought it up to me. Nice answer btw.

Comment: @hakre yes, they are appended to the environment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872152/6309 and below.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that answer does not show the variables are marked for export. At least not to me. Anyway, I should do my own homework here, e.g. https://superuser.com/q/450868/63279 or https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export .

Answer (score 6):

I think this can be helpful

`RUN echo "export FOO=bar" >> /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Most paths to running Docker containers don't read `.bashrc` or other shell dotfiles; adding lines to these files usually has no effect.