# can't install ElasticSearch image, with java 8

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, java-8, dockerfile

I used the official docker image for els (elasticsearch:6.6.1), and I get the following error, when I run the image:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

from searching online, there is problem with the JAVA, its using, and JAVA 8 is recommended.

I tried to make dockerfile that takes els:6.6.1 image, and install java8 on it:

```
FROM elasticsearch:6.6.1
RUN yum install -y  java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
RUN export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64/bin/
```

When I run it, I don't see JAVA_HOME env changing to the path I gave, and I still get the above error.

Do you know why?

Comment: Try `ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/xxx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set environment variables by using `ENV` instead of `RUN export`.

```
FROM elasticsearch:6.6.1
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64
```

You can see more explanation by VonC [docker ENV vs RUN export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379393/docker-env-vs-run-export).