# Make docker file from local image?

Tags: docker

I have docker file which make image.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

RUN export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
RUN export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

`docker build -f dockers/mydocker -t python .`

then I would like to make images from this image.

There are listed image named basic `docker images`

Then in another Dockerfile.

```
FROM python
ADD ./Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
```

When I try to build this dockerfile

There comes like this

`FROM docker.io/library/python`

Does this mean I can use local image to build next image?

I need to make local repository for this purpose ??

Or any other way to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably working fine, but you should be careful to pick names that don't conflict with standard Docker Hub image names.

A Docker image name has the form `registry.example.com/path/name`.  If you don't explicitly specify a registry, it always defaults to `docker.io` (this can't be changed), and if you don't specify a path either, it defaults to `docker.io/library/name`.  This is true in all contexts – the `docker build -t` option, the `docker run` image name, Dockerfile `FROM` lines, and anywhere else an image name appears.

That means that, when you run `docker build -t python`, you're creating a local image that has the same name as the [Docker Hub `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python).  The `docker build` diagnostics are showing you the expanded name.  It should actually be based on your local image, though; Docker won't contact a remote registry unless the image is missing locally or you explicitly tell it to.

I'd recommend choosing some unambiguous name here.  You don't specifically need a Docker Hub account, but try to avoid bare names that will conflict with standard images.

```sh
# this will work even if you don't "own" this Docker Hub name
docker build -f Dockerfile.base -t whitebear/python .
```

```sh
FROM whitebear/python
...
```

(You may have some trouble seeing the effects of your base image since [`RUN export` doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379393/docker-env-vs-run-export); change those lines in the base image to `ENV` instead.)

Comment: Thank you, my local file worked fine and your suggestion is best practice. naming like `-t whitebear/python`. I will obey this rule