# Overwriting of environment variables in Dockerfile with passed by `--build-arg`

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, cicd

I am building two docker images, one is a base docker image, and another is a custom image.

The custom image is build from base image, but I want to assign different environment variables in the image.

For example, I prepare following Dockerfiles for these two images.

**For base image:**

```
# base.Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
ARG MY_ENV
ENV MY_ENV=${MY_ENV}

# RUNs to install basic tools
# ...
```

**For custom image**

```
# base.Dockerfile
FROM my_base_image
ARG MY_ENV
ENV MY_ENV=${MY_ENV}
ENV IMAGE='This container is from a custom image'
# RUNs to setup custom images
# ...
```

Then build and run like follows.

```bash
# build a base image
docker build --file 'base.Dockerfile' \
  --build-arg MY_ENV='my_value_in_base' \
  --tag 'my_base_image' . 

# build a custom image
docker build --file 'custom.Dockerfile' \
  --build-arg MY_ENV='my_value_in_custom' \
  --tag 'my_custom_image' .
```

I expected that in
I expected that `'my_value_in_custom'` is stored in `MY_ENV` in `my_custom_image`, but `'my_value_in_base'` is stored.

```
$ docker run  my_custom_image env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=9fd195c99739
MY_ENV=my_value_in_base
IMAGE=This container is from custom image
HOME=/root
```

How can I overwrite `MY_ENV` when I build the custom image?

`docker run -e MY_ENV='my_value_in_custom'` changes the environment variables in the container, but this is not what I am looking for as I want to change the environment variables in the custom image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's not possible to replace environment variables in the specific way you suggest.

The [documentation on Dockerfile `ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables) notes:

> Environment variables defined using the `ENV` instruction always override an `ARG` instruction of the same name.

You're probably in this case.  In the second Dockerfile, an environment variable `$MY_ENV` is defined (from the base image), and so even though there's an `ARG` without an `ENV` before it in *this* Dockerfile, the extant environment variable still takes precedence.

In practice you may not need to set this variables in a Dockerfile at all.  You can also specify environment variable values when you run a container, and this is a more appropriate way to specify many values (related host names, credentials).  The `docker run -e' invocation at the end of your question does this, and for a user-provided setting, I'd frequently expect that to be correct.

If you really need to override the environment variable in the derived image, and the value really needs to be build-time configurable, then you need to give the `ARG` a different name.

```bash
FROM my_base_image
ARG CUSTOM_MY_ENV
ENV MY_ENV=${CUSTOM_MY_ENV}
```

```bash
docker build --file 'custom.Dockerfile' \
  --build-arg CUSTOM_MY_ENV='my_value_in_custom' \
  --tag 'my_custom_image' .
```

Comment: I also learned we can't `RUN export MY_ENV=${MY_ENV}` https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379487/ 
I will store value as a file.